# Property 'value' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['value']

Tags: angular

Hola estoy usando ANGULAR 13 y me da este fallo, se que es por ANGULAR 13, ya que con la versión 11 esto no pasaba. Tengo que poner VALUE de esta forma ['value'], pero no se de que manera, estoy empezando a programar en Angular y voy un poco perdido. Muchas gracias de antemano.

El fallo me sale en esta línea:  `this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;`

```
import { state } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      value: null
    }
  };

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onGoToEdit (item: any): void {
    this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], this.navigationExtras);
  }

  onGoToSee (item: any): void {
    this.navigationExtras.state.value = item;
    this.router.navigate(['details'], this.navigationExtras);
  }

  onGoToDelete (item: any): void {
    alert('Deleted');
  }

}
```

Comment: Literalmente te lo está indicando -> `this.navigationExtras.state['value'] = item;`

Comment: Si pongo eso el error no se quita sigue con el mismo problema. El Visual Studio me dice que El objeto es posiblemente "undefined". Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`this.navigationExtras.state.['value']` para acceder al campo

`this.navigationExtras.state?.['value']` para asegurarte de que exista y no te de el error de undefined

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente actualizaste a una mejor versión del intellisense y este ve que por definición navigation.state es de la siguiente forma

```
state?: {
    [k: string]: any;
}
```

lo que básicamente significa que es un objeto dinámico que puede tener distintas propiedades que se generan en runtime, por lo que no se puede saber que propiedades tiene hasta que está en ejecución, entonces el intellisense no sabe que tiene la propiedad `value` y te pide que accedas a esta de otra forma, la cual es:

```
this.navigationExtras.state['value']
```

recordar que a las propiedades de un objeto se puede acceder de 2 formas

ejemplo

```
class Persona {
  nombre: string;
}

var persona = new Persona();

console.info(persona.nombre, persona['nombre'])
```